# assertConfirmation not displaying in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am new to Selenium, I am using Selenium IDE to record test scripts.

I am having trouble while executing one of the recorded test cases in Firefox. It is a simple test case which clicks a button and then clicks on OK button of the pop up window .This is the [page link](http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2013/10/table.html) for which I am creating script.

Below are the three steps recorded from IDE

[image]

The problem is that after the second step, i.e., click step, no pop up is being shown, the same happens in the next step.

The pop up is not displayed yet the test case gets executed correctly.

Could someone please let me know why I am not able to view the pop up ?

Comment: In selenium IDE, the pop up window will be closed immediately once it pops up and is not visible. this is normal behaviour